# With -O2 compiler makes NRVO and delivers incorrect result (from gcc 7 on)

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code with gcc-6 -O2 was compiling and delivering a correct result. However, after switching to gcc 7.3 or gcc 8.2 with -O2 enabled, a compiler performs NRVO and does not deliver the correct result. Any advice, why NRVO is enabled in this case and whether it is a valid c++?

Clang-6,clang-7 and Intel compiler deliver the expected result with O3 enabled. When -fno-elide-constructors is passed to gcc7.3, the NRVO is prevented and the result is as expected.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using Coordinates = std::array<double, 3>;

Coordinates map( const Coordinates& c, size_t level )
{
   Coordinates result{ c[1], c[2], c[0] };

   if( level != 0 )
   {
     result =  map( result, level - 1);
   }

   return result;
}

int main( )
{
   Coordinates vecOfCoordinates = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
   size_t level = 1;

   auto result = map( vecOfCoordinates, level );

   std::cout << "result = (" << result[0] << ", " << result[1] << ", " << result[2] << "), should be (3, 1, 2)" << std::endl;

   return 0;

}
```

g++-6 -O2 : result = (3, 1, 2), should be (3, 1, 2)

g++-7: result = (3, 1, 2), should be (3, 1, 2)

g++-7 -O2: result = (3, 1, 3), should be (3, 1, 2)

g++-7 -O2 -fno-elide-constructors: result = (3, 1, 2), should be (3, 1, 2)

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a GCC bug.  Report it.  If it isn't, the gcc developers will point out why your code is UB.  I don't think the problem is the NRVO, the problem is that the *assignment* from the function result is being elided.

Comment: Is the behavior still present in current GCC 7 (7.4, 2018-Dec) and current GCC 8 (8.3, 2019-Feb)?

Comment: Yes, it is present in GCC 8.3.

Comment: This issue was fixed in GCC 8.4: https://godbolt.org/z/186crnWxo; It is also present in GCC 9.2 and fixed in GCC 9.3: https://godbolt.org/z/ssbv61zvY